# How to determine when to start a counter to ensure it never catches the previous counter

Tags: matlab, optimization, time, schedule

I have a problem where I have several events that are occurring in a project, the events happen semi-concurrently, where they do not start at the same time but multiple can still be occurring at once.
Each event is a team of people working on a linear task, starting at the beginning and then working their way to the end. Their progress is based on a physical distance.
I essentially need to figure out each events start time in order for no teams to be at the same location, nor passing eachother, at any point.

I am trying to program this in MATLAB so that the output would be the start and end time for each event. The idea would be to optimize the total time taken for the project.

I am not sure where to begin with something like this so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct, you just want to optimize the "calendar" of events with limited resources (aka space/teams).

This kind of problems are those called NP and there is no "easy" way to search for the best solution.

You here have two options:

1. **Greedy like algorithm:** You will have your solution in a resonable time but it won't be the best one.
2. **Brute force like algorithm:** You will find the best solution but maybe not in the time you need it.

Usually if the amount of events is low you can go for 2nd option but if don't you may need to go for the first one.

No mather which one you choose first thing you will need to do is to compute if a solution is valid. What does this mean? It means to check for every event wheter if it collisions whith others in time, space and teams.

So lets imagine the problem of making the calendar on a University. There you have to think about:

- Students
- Teacher
- Classroom

So for each event I have to check if another event have same students, teacher or classroom at the same time. First of all I will check the events that match in time with the actual event. Then I will compare the actual event with all the others.

Once you have this done you could just write a greedy algorithm that starts placing events on time just checking if it collides with some other.